# Javascript Require in browser console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When entering javascript the in the browsers console window:

**1)**

The following code works:

```
alert('hi');
```

**2)**

The following doesn't:

```
(function() {
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.src = 'http://www.myrandomwebsite.com/myjs.js';
document.head.appendChild(scr);
myfunc();
})()
```

where the **myjs.js** folder contains:

```
var myfunc = function(){alert('hi')};
```

**Explaining 2)**
the snippet of code entered in this case does cause the following code to appear at the end of the **header** tag in the source code:

```
<script src="http://www.myrandomwebsite.com/myjs.js"></script>
```

but the function **myfunc** isn't being recognized, because I get the following error message:

> VM132:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunc is not defined

Which leads me to believe that as a security measure, browsers don't run javascript code that is edited after the page has loaded, or something along those lines.

**QUESTION:** Is there a workaround of some sorts here? Whether it be a function that works like `require('...');` in most programming languages. **but It can't be** by installing any special extension, just something that works on the fly.

I move around a lot, and work on different computers, and would love to be able to use some of the code I have without needing to always carry a USB with me.

________________________ **UPDATE** ________________________

The solution @Jared Smith proposed worked perfectly. Now there is one instance where it doesn't work (and I understand why). When a site has a Content-Security-Policy that doesn't allow scripts to be loaded from other URLs or any connections to be loaded:

**for instance:**

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com
Content-Security-Policy: connect-src 'self' https://apis.google.com
```

And this makes perfect sense. My situation is that I have my own code that I run, however I wanted to be able to have this code stored on another site, and use it when I travel or am on other computers, without the need of extracting them from a USB.

Now I understand sites whitelisting what sources scripts are loaded from for security reasons, but I don't understand why there isn't an exception when it is done by the **developers console**. CSP is used mostly to prevent XSS attacks and such, but someone who is in the console is purposely using code and testing features.

**QUESTION:** Is there some feature in the console that might allow for scripts to be loaded from an alternative site? I have been fiddling with the **Source Script Snippets** but haven't been able to find an option. Or might there be some other unrelated work around?

Comment: You need to wait for the script tag's `onload` event.

Comment: @JaredSmith how so? If I go on a page and it loads completely, and then open inspect element, go to the console, that is when I want to execute code. Everything is already loaded by then, but that error still takes place.

Comment: `src.onload = function(){ myfunc(); };`. The browser has to fetch the script src which is an async operation, you have to use a callback.

Comment: @JaredSmith oh interesting. So would the solution be to just replace `myfunc();` with `src.onload = function(){ myfunc(); };`? And if a website uses ajax constantly, would the source never fully load and hence never make that call?

Comment: @JaredSmith I managed to get it to work here on Stackoverflow, but not all sites seem to work. For instance if a site has HTTPS, and the wesite is HTTP, there is an error that says it has to be HTTPS. So the obvious work around there would be to make a site that uses HTTPS and another that uses HTTP with the same code. Do you see other situations that might cause issues for some sites?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what AJAX is. AJAX is *asynchronous*, meaning the code keeps right on marching and the async ops get queued up in the event loop. It will load as soon as it reaches the end of the file. It doesn't block to wait for async requests. So no, it will fully load unless it has a syntax error.

Comment: As for the HTTPS business, yeah of course. Serve everything HTTPS. Don't mix and match, the browser doesn't like that (as you've discovered).

Comment: @JaredSmith ohhh interesting! Once I get the chance to test it over SSL I will. Thanks so much man! If you make an aswer post here, I will be more than happy to have it as the accepted answer since you were the first to have explained it.

Comment: Done deal. Fleshed out the explanation a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of an explanation is in order here.

When you add a script tag with a src dynamically the browser will fire off a request for the JavaScript file. But this operation, unlike a regular tag initially on the page, is *asynchronous*, it doesn't block. What this means is that the next line of code (in your case a call to `myfunc`) gets executed immediately, while the file is still being fetched. So if you want to defer code execution until after that script has been fetched, parsed, and executed, you need to register a callback. We can do this by listening for the script element's `load` event. There are two ways:

```
scr.addEventListener('load', function() { myfunc(); });
```

and assigning the function to the script elements `onload` property. The only real difference is that the `addEventListener` way allows you to attach multiple listeners, where as `scr.onload` can only have one value (like any other object property).

Comment: beautiful explanation

Comment: Heyy there @Jared Smith, I wanted to follow u on the interesting discussion. Code has been working great, though I found 1 specific situation that might be a bit tricky to fix. I updated my Original Post with the new information, could you check it out and tell me what you think?

Comment: @Webeng There isn't anything special about the console in this regard. Note that the external server  will need to be CORS enabled for you to use cross origin sources.

Comment: yes I placed the appropriate line of code in the .htaccess file in the server, and the code worked fine in all sites that didn't have a Content-Security-Policy set. Though I'm still trying to see what I can do with sites that have a CSP. Weird that the console is also affected by it, I would have assumed that the console would be more powerful since it is used by developers.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.text = 'function sayHi() { alert("hi")}';
document.head.appendChild(scr);
sayHi()
```

...aaaaaand this works:

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js';
scr.onload = function() {
  $(function(){
    $('body').css({backgroundColor: 'red'});
  });
}
document.head.appendChild(scr);
```

Comment: OP is specifically asking about using a url source, not inline script.

Comment: Thank you for the response John! But what I want is to use code that is on another website. With your code snippet, I would have to remember all the code and rewrite it. I would like to have my own website with code on it, and then it's easy for me to access that way.